# How to check if LinqDataSource is empty after selecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, is-empty, linqdatasource

I have an `asp.NET` application where I use a `LinqDataSource` control to fill a `ListView` control.  Here's the code for my `LinqDataSource` control's `OnSelecting` command:

```
protected void lds_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEvenArgs e)
{
    var db = new Models.EF.Entities();
    e.Result = from x in db.Sliders
                where x.IsPublic == true
                select x;
}
```

This works great but now I want to run an if statement in the case that the result is empty.  How can I see if the result is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Any` method. Plus, [`LinqDataSourceSelectEvenArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourceselecteventargs.result(v=vs.110).aspx) stores the data as an `object` so cast so use the `as` to get the `IEnumerable<T>` on which you can run the `Any`:

```
e.Result = (from x in db.Sliders
            where x.IsPublic == true
            select x);

var collection = e.Result as IEnumerable<Slider>;
if(collection != null && !collection.Any()) 
{ 
    /*your code*/
}
```

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok, but I actually asked for it to run only if the result IS empty, so if(!collection.Any()) {} works, thanks for leading me to a solution.

Comment: Happy it helped :)